# How can i run jenkins, maven & git all on the docker : windows

Tags: git, docker, maven, jenkins, devops

Newbie to devops, looking help to run Jenkins, maven & git on docker.

Note:

1. already downloaded jenkins/jenkins:lts image
2. looking forward to having a method wherein I can pull more of the images under a single container

Comment: It's not possible to create a single container from multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Please add more detail to the question.
If you are trying to run maven builds on Kubernetes/OpenShift and are looking for an image which has maven, jdk, git installed in it, you can use -

```
registry.redhat.io/openshift4/ose-jenkins-agent-maven:<v4.5.0>
```

See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/openshift_images/using_images/images-other-jenkins-agent.html for more details.